# Solve $y^2 y'' = c y'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $y^2 y'' = c y'$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. I tried using separation of variables but I didn't get the answer.

Comment: Then what to do for $y^2$.

Comment: I got $v' = y''/y'$ but don't know for $y^2$.

Comment: Is the answer correct ? $y- \frac{c}{c_1}+ c_2 \log(c_1 y - c) = x + c_3$

Comment: Plug it in and see!

Comment: yes I got that. After that $v = \frac{-c}{y} + c_1$. Then I substitute $v = y'$. Solving that ODE i get the answer which i mentioned earlier.

Comment: What is the independent variable?

Answer (score 0):

Case $1$: $c=0$

Then $y^2y''=0$

$y^2=0$ or $y''=0$

$y=0$ or $y=C_1\text{independent variable}+C_2$

Case $2$: $c\neq0$

Then $y^2y''=cy'$

Let $u=y'$ ,

Then $y^2u\dfrac{du}{dy}=cu$

$u=0$ or $\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{c}{y^2}$

$u=0$ or $u=C_1-\dfrac{c}{y}$

$y'=0$ or $y'=\dfrac{C_1y-c}{y}$

$y=C$ or $\dfrac{y}{C_1y-c}dy=d~\text{independent variable}$

......